# Visual Studio 2008 search and replace regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, replace

I have a large solution with a lot of lines that I need to replace.
In Visual Studio, you can search and replace with the aid of regular expressions.

I want to replace lines like:

```
rst.Fields("CustomerName").Value
rst.Fields("Address").Value
rst.Fields("Invoice").Value
```

To:

```
row("CustomerName").ToString()
row("Address").ToString()
row("Invoice").ToString()
```

Thus keeping the dynamic text part, which can vary.

Is this possible and how?

**Update, solution:**
Search: `rst.Fields{\(.*\)}\.Value`
Replace: `rst\1.ToString()`

Thanks JaredPar!

Comment: Possibly, yes. We need more detail, though. Which parts are invariant? For example, is the word "Command" invariant? Or will you be doing this on a method-by-method basis?

Comment: Ok, edited the post with a better example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

- Search Expression: `ASpecificCommand(\(.*\))\.ASpecificProperty`
- Replace Expression: `ATotallyDifferentCommand\1.ATotallyDifferentProperty`

Note: This is not a perfect solution.  Since there are `(`s involved and hence matching of nested parens, a regex won't ever be a perfect solution.  However it should get the job done for the specific pattern you posted

Comment: Very very close, this did put me on the right track (using backreferences in regular expressions). The solution needs {} instead of (). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer and solution provided helpful in doing a find-replace on messageboxes.

This worked in Visual Studio 2008 (VB .NET):

Example:

```
MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry","Error")
```

Find What:

```
MessageBox.Show{(.*,*)}
```

Replace WIth:

```
Error.ShowError\1\2
```

Results in:

```
Error.ShowError("Invalid Entry","Error")
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have it nailed.  It's what is called a "tagged expression" and you can see another example here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/12/replace-in-files-tagged-expressions-vstipfind0016.aspx